# Parsing Twitch JSON response

Tags: python, json, parsing

I would like to get the user list from someones Twitch channel.
Heres my current code:

```
j = urllib2.urlopen('http://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/graf_pk/chatters')
j_obj = json.load(j)
print(j_obj['chatters']['viewers'])
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
[u'pokenuts123', u'realthotsritehere']
```

I expect an output of all the user names that can be iterated threw like:

```
for x in users:
  print x
```

Comment: Yes, your output is a list, you can iterate through it, as you indicated, what is your problem?

Comment: @AnandSKumar my bad I didn't think it was that simple. First time ever using JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result doesn't need to be parsed

```
j = urllib2.urlopen('http://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/graf_pk/chatters')
j_obj = json.load(j)
u=j_obj['chatters']['viewers']
for x in u:
    print x
```